# How to open CSV file from target after execute TEXT_IO Procedure

Tags: csv, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have code in which generate CSV file from select statement. For this purpose I used TEXT_IO procedure. This procedure created CSV File on target path. Now I want open CSV file from target path after execute procedure.

**CODE:**

```
PROCEDURE REPORT_CSV IS

 CURSOR c_data IS
 SELECT hofid,
       mofid,
       mofname,
       rid,
       cnicno
 FROM   mof
 where hofid = '1131716869';

 v_file        client_text_io.file_type;   
 v_delimiter VARCHAR2(1) := ',';

BEGIN

 v_file := CLIENT_TEXT_IO.FOpen( 'E:\Report_MOF.csv', 'W' );

 FOR cur_rec IN c_data LOOP
 CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE(v_file,
                  cur_rec.hofid    || ',' ||
                  cur_rec.mofid    || ',' ||
                  cur_rec.mofname      || ',' ||
                  cur_rec.rid      || ',' ||
                  cur_rec.cnicno);
 END LOOP;

 client_text_io.fclose (v_file);

 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 MESSAGE(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);

END;
```

Comment: Why do you use `CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE`, didn't you already created the file?

Comment: No I create new file then put data into csv file